# Stationarity test - What is wrong with this timeseries?

Tags: r, time-series, interpretation, stationarity, cointegration

Following is a timeseries for which I want to test for stationarity. Visually, this timeseries looks stationary as the price is fluctuation between `$22.6` and `$23.1`. However, both `adf` and `kpss` tests are showing this timeseries to be non-stationary. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong with stationarity testing?

The problem is that this timeseries is making spurious/ nonsense relationships with other non-stationary timeseries while doing the cointegration test. Is there a different test I should use to flag such timeseries?

[image: Stationary or Non-Stationary?]

[image: ACF]

[image]

[image: ACF and PACF or residuals]

```
time_s <- c(22.56, 22.72, 22.87, 22.95, 22.92, 22.88, 22.91, 22.83, 22.86, 
22.75, 22.74, 22.6651, 22.6, 22.69, 22.77, 22.84, 22.91, 22.87, 
22.8, 22.79, 22.84, 22.84, 22.89, 23.01, 23.02, 23.06, 23.05, 
23.1, 23.11, 23.07, 23.09, 23.09, 23.07, 23.11, 23.135, 23.16, 
23.16, 23.14, 23.15, 23.16, 23.14, 23.14, 23.08, 23.08, 23.05, 
22.99, 23.07, 23.09, 23.07, 23.1, 23.1, 23.06, 23.1, 23.1, 23.1, 
23.1, 23.09, 23.12, 23.12, 23.03, 23.05, 22.99, 23.02, 23.03, 
23.04, 23.04, 23, 23.02, 23.01, 23.03, 22.9, 22.94, 22.86, 22.84, 
22.82, 22.87, 22.92, 22.94, 22.96, 22.97, 23, 22.99, 23.02, 23.07, 
23.1, 23.125, 23.1, 23.09, 23.06, 23.06, 23.02, 23.02, 23, 23, 
23.03, 23, 22.99, 22.93, 22.96, 22.96, 22.97, 23.03, 23.07, 23.08, 
23.07, 23.12, 23.13, 23.13, 23.08, 23.12, 23.13, 23.09, 23.11, 
23.12, 23.13, 23.08, 23.07, 23.04, 23.08, 23.07, 23.08, 23.1, 
23.1, 23.12, 23.13, 23.12, 23.12, 23.12, 23.09, 23.08, 23.1, 
23.09, 23.11, 23.12, 23.04, 23.05, 23.05, 23.07, 23.09, 23.07, 
23.1, 23.1, 23.1, 23.11, 23.1, 23.1, 23.13, 23.1, 23.1, 23.1, 
23.09, 23.1, 23.07, 23.07, 23.07, 23.08, 23.08, 23.06, 23.05, 
23.07, 23.08, 23.08, 23.09, 23.08, 23.08, 23.09, 23.11, 23.09, 
23.1, 23.1, 23.11, 23.11, 23.12, 23.11, 23.12, 23.07, 23.06, 
23.05, 23.03, 23.03, 23.06, 23.08, 23.06, 23.03, 23.06, 23.05, 
23.07, 23.08, 23.08, 23.08, 23.08, 23.06, 23.08, 23.05, 23.06, 
23.04, 23.05, 23.04, 23.04, 23.06, 23.06, 23.04, 23.06, 23.062, 
23.06, 23.06, 23.06, 23.07, 23.07, 23.07, 23.06, 23.07, 23.085, 
23.07, 23.035, 23.025, 23.025, 23.025, 23.035, 23.02, 23.035, 
23.025, 23.045, 23.035, 23.04, 23.045, 23.05, 23.05, 23.055, 
23.05, 23.04, 23.045, 23.05, 23.05, 23.055, 23.05, 23.055, 23.055, 
23.055, 23.015, 23.035, 23.025, 23.035, 23.03, 23.02, 23.02, 
23.02, 23.02, 23.02, 23.02, 23.03, 23.03, 23.03, 23.03, 23.03, 
23.03, 23.03, 23.03, 23.005, 23, 23.01, 23.02, 23.01, 23.01, 
23.01, 23.01, 23.02, 23.02, 23.02, 23.03, 23.03, 23.03, 23.03, 
23.02, 23.03, 23.03, 23.03, 23.01, 23, 23.01, 23.01, 23.01, 23, 
22.99, 23, 23.01, 23, 23.01, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23.005, 23, 
23, 23.01, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23.01, 23, 23, 
23, 23, 23.01, 23, 22.99, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23.01, 22.99, 22.99, 
22.98, 22.98, 22.98, 22.99, 23, 22.99, 22.99, 22.98, 22.99, 22.99, 
23, 22.98, 22.99, 22.99, 22.98, 22.97, 22.99, 22.98, 22.99, 22.99, 
22.98, 22.98, 22.985, 22.98, 22.99, 22.98, 22.98, 22.99, 22.99, 
22.99, 22.98, 22.98, 22.98, 22.98, 22.99, 22.98, 22.98, 22.98, 
22.98, 22.98, 22.985, 22.98, 22.98, 22.98, 22.97, 22.98, 22.98, 
22.985, 22.98, 22.98, 22.97, 22.98, 22.98, 22.98, 22.98, 22.98, 
22.98)
```

Here is the adf result -

```
df_res = urca::ur.df(time_s, type = "none", lags = 1)
summary(df_res)

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression none 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 - 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.13235 -0.01024 -0.00057  0.00943  0.13518 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
z.lag.1    2.479e-05  5.967e-05   0.416    0.678  
z.diff.lag 8.908e-02  4.921e-02   1.810    0.071 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.02662 on 374 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.009314,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.004016 
F-statistic: 1.758 on 2 and 374 DF,  p-value: 0.1738


Value of test-statistic is: 0.4155 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau1 -2.58 -1.95 -1.62
```

Following is the kpss test result

```
res = urca::ur.kpss(ts(time_s), type="tau", lags="short")
summary(res)

####################### 
# KPSS Unit Root Test # 
####################### 

Test is of type: tau with 5 lags. 

Value of test-statistic is: 0.5919 

Critical value for a significance level of: 
                10pct  5pct 2.5pct  1pct
critical values 0.119 0.146  0.176 0.216
```

From a comment made by the OP: "This series is of a ETF called Invesco BulletShares 2021 Hi Yld Corp ticker "BSJL". This stock has almost perfect cointegration with Gold (GLD ETF) and a few other asset classes, which does not make much sense. I am curious to know if there is a way to flag such a series so they don't make these false cointegrations with other assets."

Comment: Any exploration of stationarity should start with an ACF and PACF plot. Your series looks nonstationary (both mean and variance). Let's see the ACF and PACF to get a sense of the autocorrelation function. Given that the variance is decreasing over time, modeling ln(y) instead of y should help stabilize the variance.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, when it comes to stationarity, I would say nothing beats the plot of the original data. Fortunately, OP has included it right from the start.

Comment: @RichardHardy: Seeing the original series is also valuable. But the series may, for example, have a linear trend and yet this doesn't have to mean that the process has a linear trend because anything can happen in a small sample of say 60-100 observations.  When we look at the original plot there is only one point per random variable and we are trying to use it to get a sense of each random variable. On the other hand, in the ACF plot each lag is computed on many observations; lag 1 on n-1, lag 2 on n-2, lag 3 on n-3 observations. We can draw more solid conclusions from the ACF/PACF plots.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, I think this is a false distinction. If we had one point per random variable and did not impose additional assumptions on how they are related (some form of stationarity), ACF and PACF would be meaningless; we could not interpret them as estimating (pseudo) true parameters which we routinely do when looking at ACF/PACF. Therefore, the purported solidity of ACF and PACF comes entirely from the additional assumptions. But a trained statistician can choose whether to mentally impose these same assumptions or not when looking at the original plot, and that is the benefit of that.

Comment: @RichardHardy: So I understand your position better, what do you use the original series for? What conclusions are you looking to draw from a visual of the series? My point is that we are not warranted to draw any conclusions from a visual of the original series. On the other hand, we can draw tentative conclusions from the ACF/PACF of the original series, and can make decisions based on the ACF/PACF of the residual (in a preliminary model).

Comment: @ColorStatistics, I do not see how ACF and PACF which are calculated from the original data enable any more robust/trustworthy conclusions than are supported by the original data itself. Any additional robustness must come from additional assumptions. When it comes to stationarity, I tend to learn more from a plot of the original data than ACF/PACF as similar ACF/PACF can come from somewhat dissimilar original series (in respects relevant to stationarity).

Comment: @RichardHardy: 1. Imagine a simulation from a stationary series; we may well produce a series of 100 observations that look like a random walk (suggesting non-stationarity). But the sample ACF/PACF plot of this series is far less likely to have us draw the wrong conclusion - that the series is nonstationary.

Comment: @RichardHardy: 2. See Brockwell & Davis - 1996 on page 131; they fit an AR(2) model to a series with a clear downward trend; the series clearly suggests that there is a downward trend (nonstationary) and yet they use the sample ACF/PACF plots to argue that they are consistent with the series being stationary (despite the clear trend in the plot of the original series).

Comment: @ColorStatistics, I bet that if that hypothetical series looks like a random walk, its ACF and PACF will reflect that, too. The ACF/PACF is merely a summary of the original series; they cannot show anything that is not in it. (But I am curious to see a simulated example!) Moreover, your example addresses an irrelevant question (given our context): we care about P(model|data), not P(data|model). What is the title of B&D chapter/section? I do not have the 1996 edition but some other.

Comment: @RichardHardy: Let me reiterate this point - When we look at the original plot there is only one point per random variable and we are trying to use it to get a sense of each random variable. On the other hand, in the ACF plot each lag is computed on many observations; lag 1 on n-1, lag 2 on n-2, lag 3 on n-3 observations. The ACF/PACF of a series is far less likely to have us draw an incorrect conclusion than a plot of the original series. I still have not heard what you use the original series for? What conclusions can you draw from a plot of the original series? The answer is - none.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, let me reiterate that if we had one point per random variable and did not impose additional assumptions on how they are related (some form of stationarity), the empirical ACF and PACF would be meaningless. And the rest of what I said on that topic. The conclusions I can draw from the original series is whether what I would eventually see in ACF/PACF is due to a trend, a structural break or a unit root component; all of them may look the same in an ACF/PACF plot, simply because ACF/PACF compresses (relevant!) information while the original plot does not.

Comment: Of course we impose the assumptions of stationarity and ergodicity. Who is arguing with that? It is false that the ACF/PACF of a unit root and of a linearly trending process will look the same; the ACF of the first with be persistent whereas that of the second one will not. Hopefully we can have a third person arbitrate this debate.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, thank you for an inspiring discussion. I suggest we terminate it here, and if there are any further questions, we can open a new thread or two and continue in a Q&A form rather than use comments.

Comment: Thank you, Richard.

Comment: Thank you both! I have added the ACF and PACF of residuals. I still wonder if there is a test to flag timeseries that have very low variance as given in the example above?

Comment: @RichardHardy: I thought about it some more and I see the point you were making. You are right. Under the assumption of stationarity of the mean, in a series of 100 observations we have 100 observations of a process with a constant mean. Now, imagine a simulation from a stationary process. 100 observations have been drawn. By sheer luck, they could have been drawn in a way that would falsely suggest a trend or a unit root.

Comment: @RichardHardy: On the other hand, it is much, much, much less likely to draw these 100 observations in such a way that their ACF is persistent (suggestive of an integrated series) when the true process is stationary. To do that would require something close to magic because the order of these observations has to be such that lag 1 (based on 99 observations of adjacent observations) is highly statistically significant , then lag 2 (based on 98 observations of 2 period lags) is highly significant but a little less so than lag 1, etc. I hope this clears it up for you. Thanks again.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, thank you! I am glad our understandings are converging, hopefully not only to each other but also to the truth! Even so, I am not persuaded by your example. I am puzzled by how a process could look like a random walk yet not display its characteristic ACF/PACF, as the former determines the latter. I am also not convinced that what you suggest is more vs. less likely is actually so. (If anything, I am talking about finite samples, not asymptotics, so ACF/PACF are not estimated with perfect precision.) But again, perhaps comments is not the ideal way of discussing this.

Comment: Included a few more charts, I hope this will help answer this question. This series is of a ETF called Invesco BulletShares 2021 Hi Yld Corp ticker "BSJL". This stock has almost perfect cointegration with Gold (GLD ETF) and a few other asset classes, which does not make much sense. I am curious to know if there is a way to flag such a series so they don't make these false cointegrations with other assets.

Comment: @RichardHardy: Haha, yes. Hopefully we are converging to the truth.

Answer (score 5):

From an application domain point of view, what is "wrong" with this series is that this is a *bond index* with a fixed maturity date ("on or about" December 15th, 2021, see information at Invesco [here](https://www.invesco.com/us/financial-products/etfs/product-detail?audienceType=Investor&ticker=BSJL)).

Bonds have a fixed value at maturity, which is why volatility has been decreasing. There are other types of bond indexes where they are replaced by longer dated bonds when they get closer to maturity to keep the index's duration relatively stable.

Visually, this does *not* look stationary, at all. The changing variance is very clear. But you should not rely on the ADF test for this, because the error term in the test regression is assumed to have a constant variance, so its conclusions are not useful anyway.

To answer your question more directly: given that this series will end a few days from now and you will most likely not have time to ever invest in it, I would take some time to consider why you're looking at it at all rather than whether you can figure out a reliable scheme to "automatically flag" it as being problematic.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Your answer makes the logic behind the changing variance very clear. Problem - I have a few hundred timeseries on which I ran cointegration tests. However, there are many time-series in my dataset that have low variance, and around these timeseries other timesries with high variance fluctuate showing strong cointegration, even though there is no relation. Especially bonds and few etfs have low variance. Is there a way to filter these out?

Comment: @Saurabh: Note that it works best when you break down your task into separate components and try to understand each of them separately. You would get more of a response if you posted several focused questions rather than one that spills into many more questions.

Comment: @ColorStatistics: I have maintained a single question from the beginning. I have added more details as Chris wanted to understand why I am even considering comparing this series to which it doesn't have any relation.

Comment: Have you checked that each variable in your cointegration relationships is integrated of the same order?

Comment: Yes, all the timeseries in this study have unit root.